# how we use mobile keyboard key event in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

- I can use key Event when use click the phone keyboard enter key and go to next Edit Text and next to another submit button.
- I am trying to get the user phone keyboard key click event but I don't know what is method use for this event in flutter.
  **Problem** I can use the input type method for keyboard as numeric but I can not get the key event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set some basic functions on keyboard button so you can try this method

change event by TextInputAction

- TextInputAction.done
- TextInputAction.search
- TextInputAction.continueAction
- TextInputAction.emergencyCall

and more.........

```
TextFormField(

      maxLines: 1,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
     
    ),
```